# Need assistance on invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r

I am new to R and in learning phase. While plotting histogram and Frequency polygon code i am getting an error. I am unable to debug it. Please help in understanding the error.

```
#HISTOGRAM

x=seq(200,1200,by=200)
width=200
x
freq=c(6,16,24,20,10)
freq
lowerbound=x-(width/2)
upperbound=x+(width/2)
lowerbound
upperbound
lowerbound[1]

brks=c(lowerbound[1],upperbound)
brks

y = rep(x,freq) #getting error Error in rep(x, freq) : invalid 'times' argument

hist(y,breaks = brks,xlab = "Monthly Rent",ylab = "Families",main = "Histogram)")


#Frequency Polygon

x=seq(200,1200,by=200)
width=200
x
freq=c(6,16,24,20,10)
freq
x1=c(0,x,1400)
x1
f1=c(0,freq)

f1
plot(x1,f1)

#Error: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

#plot(x1,f1,"b",xlab="Rent",ylab = "Families",main="FP")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using vectors of different length. Both `rep` and `plot` expect the two input vectors to have the same number of items.

Try this and look at where I made changes:

```
x=seq(200,1200,by=200) 
width=200 
x 
#freq=c(6,16,24,20,10) 
freq=c(6,16,24,20,10, 5) # Added one more item, 5
freq 
lowerbound=x-(width/2) 
upperbound=x+(width/2) 
lowerbound 
upperbound 
lowerbound[1]

brks=c(lowerbound[1],upperbound) 
brks

y = rep(x,freq) # No more errors here

hist(y, breaks = brks,xlab = "Monthly Rent",ylab = "Families",main = "Histogram")
```

[image]

```
x=seq(200,1200,by=200) 
x 
#freq=c(6,16,24,20,10)
freq=c(6,16,24,20,10,5,3) # Added two more items, 5 and 3
freq 
x1=c(0,x,1400) 
x1 
f1=c(0,freq)

f1 
plot(x1,f1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! If your problem is solved, please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.